# HTML Agility Pack HtmlNode.InnerText Not Working/Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to determine the inner text from the /head/title node of an HTML document. My problem arose when transitioning my code from net framework 4.7.2 to netcore 2.2. After transitioning to netcore 2.2, when loading the HTML from the server and checking the title node's `InnerText`, it is blank. However, the `InnerHtml` shows the proper text, "Appointment".

I performed a test to determine the cause of this issue. I saved an html document locally, then loaded it in and tested if the InnerText showed up properly, which it did.

In the image linked below, the left side is loaded from the server, the right side from a local html file:

[image]

I don't know why there is an inconsistency here, because as you can see the OuterHtml is identical

```
<title>Appointment</title>
```

There is one difference, the node create from the HTML loaded from the server shows a new field, `isPcData = true;`

Resolved: As Jonathan commented, it was a bug with HtmlAgilityPack version 1.11.10. The  HtmlAgilityPack versions were inconsistent between my two projects, causing the discrepancy.

Comment: I fixed it by just adding /text()[1] to my html xpath selector, then using InnerText to access the text of the text node. It selects the text node inside the title tags, and then it allows me to access the text. Might be a bug with htmlagilitypack

Comment: I checked the encoding and it's the same UTF 8 encoding for both

Comment: Which version are you using? The v1.11.10 was up for a few hours before a hotfix was done in the v1.11.11 due to a similar bug as your

Comment: I was using the version 1.11.10. I updated and its fixed, thank you. On a side note, why was my question voted down? Is the question too specific?